# Jenkins unstash does not work but directory is not clean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkinsfile I run a `stash` on the build node as follows

```
stash name: "test-stash", includes: "target/bin/Release/**"
```

which successfully works and stashes about 33 files.

Later in the pipeline stuff gets unstashed on another node as follows

```
dir(pwd()) {
   unstash "test-stash"
}
```

The stash runs trough without error however when I check the content of the stash there are completely different files in it.

So to have the directory clean, I try to do a cleanup before which gives me the following error

```
...
[Pipeline] echo
[INFO] Unstash `test-stash` to 'd:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\myapp_release_master@2'
[Pipeline] dir
Running in d:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\myapp_release_master@2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
[ERROR] Unable to clean directory 'd:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\myapp_release_master@2'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: d:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\myapp_release_master@2 does not exist
```

So my question is why stash does not work as expected and why it is not possible to clean the folder.

Comment: why do you have `dir(pwd()) {` ? seems quite unnecessary to me.

Comment: Maybe but that's not really the issue here... Same effect I have removing the `dir(pwd())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stash to the `pwd()` seems not to work. However doing the stash in a subfolder of the `pwd()` seemes to work.

```
dir("./test") {
   unstash "test-stash"
}
```